# How to set up some build-in variables for powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have some powershell scripts , and those scripts need to use some string data which I store in a file .
Does there exists any way can let me set up some build-in variables , and I can direct access this variables between many powershell scripts . So I don't need to frequently open the file and read the data in each of my powershell scripts

thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just assign it to a variable as `$foo = 'blah'`? And as long as you run the scripts in the same PS session, each script could get to `$foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think global variables are what you need here, this article describes the different [variable scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx).

It seems like you might have quite a few variables so one approach would be to create a Custom Object with multiple properties and store the object in the global scope, that way only one global variable is created.

```
# Create a custom psobject for storing parameters 
$global:Parameters = "" | select Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4, Param5  

# Populate each parameter
$global:Parameters.Param1 = "parameter 1"
$global:Parameters.Param2 = "parameter 2"
$global:Parameters.Param3 = "parameter 3"
$global:Parameters.Param4 = "parameter 4"
$global:Parameters.Param5 = "parameter 5"

# refer to the parameter in other scripts
$global:Parameters.Param1
```

Answer (score 3):

you can create environment variables or define the variable in your profile

ex creating environment var:

```
PS>[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Myvar", "Test value.", "User")
PS>$env:Myvar
Test value.
```

More info here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I would put these in a PowerShell module, call it `Settings.psm1`:

```
$Settings = @{
    Var1 = 'Value1';
    Var2 = 'Value2';
}

Export-ModuleMember -Variable Settings
```

Then, in any scripts that want to use/load those settings, import your module:

```
 Import-Module (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot Build\Settings\Settings.psm1)
```

Then you can access `$Settings` in your script:

```
$Settings.Var1
$Settings.Var1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also store the information in the registry and retrieve from there.

This [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315394.aspx) explains how to do both in Powershell.

You could have one "setup" script read the file and create the registry entries, then just read those entries from the scripts that need to.